# Element of my django forms.py is not defined?

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I've got a problem with django with handling forms : I created a form with 2 fields, and I associated it to my view, but it tells me that my fields are undefined. Could you explain me please ?

I created a form in my index.html :

```
 <form action="/addUser" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label> Name of the Employee : <input type="text" name="employeeName", id="employeeName"/> </label>
    <label> Email of the Employee : <input type="email" name="employeeEmail", id="employeeEmail" /> </label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```

Then I created in views.py

```
def addUser(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreationUserForm(request.POST)

        newEmployee = Employee()
        newEmployee.name = form[employeeName]
        newEmployee.email = form[employeeEmail]
        newEmployee.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
```

And then I created in forms.py

```
class CreationUserForm(forms.Form):
    employeeName = forms.CharField(label='employeeName', max_length=254)
    employeeEmail = forms.CharField(label='employeeEmail', max_length=254)
```

So I don't understand why I get this error : name 'employeeName' is not defined

For my point of view it is...

I tried with form.employeeName too, but it considered as a non existant attribute.

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `addUser` method, both the `employeeName` and `employeeEmail` are variables, which are not defined. You want to be accessing the keys via the strings.

```py
def addUser(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreationUserForm(request.POST)

        newEmployee = Employee()
        newEmployee.name = form['employeeName']
        newEmployee.email = form['employeeEmail']
        newEmployee.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
```

also a Django suggestion - before accessing the attributes of the form, it is often useful to check that the input is valid by calling `if form.is_valid()` as defined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/